# Как обновить версию PHP?

Tags: php, denwer, php.ini

Удалил содержимое папки php5, закинул туда содержимое php-5.6.26-Win32-VC11-x86.zip. Создал php.ini, раскомментировал extension_dir="ext". Итог: ничего не работает.

Comment: "ничего не работает" винда тоже не грузится?

Comment: К счастью, грузится) Но при запуске denwer'а выпадает ошибка "Не удается получить доступ к сайту".

Comment: В логах апача есть какие-нибуть ошибки?

Comment: Нет, вот такой последний лог в access.log: 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2016:12:05:45 +0300] "GET /denwer/errors/phperror_js.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3122

Comment: Самый простой способ: CTRL+X всех папок(файлов) на сервере с главной папки html если не ошибаюсь (там где сайты размещаются). Удалить денвер и установить заново. Потом обратно закинуть все сайты в главную папку

Comment: php 5.6 вроде работает на apache 2.4..... на 2.2 вроде не должен......... у денвера апач 2.2......... вывод делайте сами...... Любой вам начнет говорить про OpenServer вместо денвера....... и это правильно.. ибо денвер давно не оновлялся, а опенсервер уже давно с php7 сидит и обновленными модулями